# Saving Sqflite data on Firebase when Online(and Logged In)

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, sqflite

I am building an application which uses SQFLITE(SQLITE) Database to save user's data by default.

I want that when users are logged in and online, this data is saved in Firebase, so that users can access their data from any device.

I have read that we'll have to create sync method to convert SFLITE's data to Firebase's NOSQL data. **How exactly can I do this? Any useful links, examples, etc. would be really helpful.**

P.S. I know Firebase has offline support, but it is not suited for my use case

Comment: maybe you can use tokens with time limits